# Short version of if var is defined for ansible templates

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Jinja2 in Ansible templates allows this type of expression in templates:

```
{% if foobar is defined %} foo_bar = {{foobar}} {% endif %}
{% if barfoo is defined %} bar_foo = {{barfoo}} {% endif %}
```

etc.

Is there any shorter version to say 'do not print this line if its variable is not defined?

Something like foo_bar = {{foobar|skip_this_line_if_undefined}}?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a macro.

```
{% macro line(key, value) -%}
    {% if not value|none  %}{{ key }} = {{ value }}{% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Then just call the macro for every key/value pair.

```
{{ line('foo_bar', foobar) }}
{{ line('bar_foo', barfoo) }}
```

Could be problematic in edge cases though. If `foobar` or `barfoo` are not defined it probably will raise an error. In the macro, `value` in any case would be defined, so the condition `is defined` doesn't make sense any more. But if null/none actually is a valid value for any of the variables, you hit the wall...

A bit longer but probably water proof:

```
{% macro line(key, value) -%}
    {% if value != omit  %}{{ key }} = {{ value }}{% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}

{{ line('foo_bar', foobar|default(omit)) }}
{{ line('bar_foo', barfoo|default(omit)) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `default(omit)` filter. For details have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-undefined-variables-and-parameters).

Comment: I need them in the templates. When I use default(omit) in the template (like this: foo={{foo|default(omit)}}) it produces: foo=__omit_place_holder__36742c2d9293968a6c6844b6c5ff0f6d24a142d2. :(

Comment: I see... this works only in playbooks. So the answer of @udondan seems to match your requirements.

Comment: in that case use default()